# Layoutinflater: inflate multiple layouts (xml) to access TextViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

I have a .xml file (download_text_item.xml) that includes a TextView to set Text in a RecyclervIew.

Now I need a **2nd .xml file (mirror_text_item.xml)** with a TextView which should also be accessible in the RecyclerView but I don`t know how to correctly inflate it in my adapter, I made a include which works through .xml but not programmatically.

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/mirrors">
<include layout="@layout/mirror_text_item"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I tried also with `container.addView` in the DownloadAdapter but somehow I can`t get it right.

mirror_text_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:clickable="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mir"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="http://www.mirror.com"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

DownloadAdapter:

```
public class DownloadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    String[] items;
    Fragment fragment;

    public DownloadAdapter(Fragment fragment, String[] items) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup container, int viewType) {
        View a, v = null;
        if (viewType == 0)
            v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.download_header_item, container, false);
        else
            v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.download_text_item, container, false);

        //mirror_text_item.xml needs to be inflated here

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    public String getSelection(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final String item = Utils.unescapeJavaString(Html.fromHtml(getSelection(position)).toString());
        holder.text.setText(item);

        if (Utils.downloadVis == 1)
        holder.mir.setText("Just testing"); //Nullpointer Exception as not inflated

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Utils.openUri(fragment, item);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView text, mir;
        private View itemView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            mir = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mir);
            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Everything works with H Raval code, except the text for the Mirror Textview, I guess the problem lies in below code:

```
@Override
    public DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup container, int viewType) {
        View a, v = null;
        if (viewType == 0)
            v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.download_header_item, container, false);
        else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.download_text_item, container, false);
            return new DownloadViewHolder(v);
        }
        if (Utils.downloadVis == 1) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mirror_text_item, container, false);
            return new MirrorViewHolder(v);
        }
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your need...its unclear what you want actually

Comment: Hi H Raval, I need to inflate the 2nd .xml (mirror_text_item.xml) so I can set the text programmatically in its TextView in the download adapter, Now I get a Nullpointerexception as it is not inflated. Refer to the 1st ,xml (download_text_item.xml) with also has a TextView which is inflated correctly.

Comment: why dont you use two textviews in one layout by hiding each as per need

Comment: Because, the Textviews are going to be filled with urls which are clickable, furthermore want to present the user with normal download links (download_text_item) and mirrors (mirror_text_item), therefore they need to be seperatly.

Comment: inside onCreateViewHolder inflatelayout as per some condition

Comment: Yes, that is the question, I don`t know how to add/inflate mirror_text_item.xml under the View v.
I wanna set Text to the TextView in onBindViewHolder as you can see in my code.

Comment: please post your both xml...and on which condition you want to change?...do you want header in both?

Comment: The .xml of download_text_item and mirror_text_item are exactly the same, only thing which is different is ofcourse the ID of the TextViews. (ID in download...xml is "text" and ID in mirror...xml is "mir".
Condition is if (Utils.downloadVis == 1), as this decides if there is a mirror string in the fetched content, if so, show another TextView (Mirrors:) in the download dialog.

Answer (score 0):

here you go.....

```
 public class DownloadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    String[] items;
    Fragment fragment;

    public DownloadAdapter(Fragment fragment, String[] items) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup container, int viewType) {
        View a, v = null;
        if (viewType == 0)
            v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.download_header_item, container, false);
        else
            v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.download_text_item, container, false);

        //mirror_text_item.xml needs to be inflated here

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    public String getSelection(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 1;
    }
 @Override
    public DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup container, int viewType) {
        View a, v = null;
        if((Utils.downloadVis == 1)){
            v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mirror_text_item, container, false);
            return new DownloadViewHolder(v);
        }else{
          v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.download_text_item, container, false);
          return new MirrorViewHolder(v);
        }

    }

     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder viewholder, final int position) {
        final String item = Utils.unescapeJavaString(Html.fromHtml(getSelection(position)).toString());

        if(viewholder instenceOf DownloadViewHolder){
            DownloadViewHolder holder = (DownloadViewHolder) viewholder;
            holder.textView.setText(item);

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Utils.openUri(fragment, item);
            }
        });
        }else{
        MirrorViewHolder holder = (MirrorViewHolder) viewholder;
            holder.textView.setText(item);

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Utils.openUri(fragment, item);
            }
        });

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

 class MirrorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private View itemView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mir);
            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }

    class DownloadViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private View itemView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx H Raval but I get many errors, for instance "cannot resolve symbol Viewholder" in public class DownloadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder>

Comment: @H Raval, I almost got it running with your code, everything works exept, the text for MirrorViewHolder  is not shown. The problem lies in the DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder.
Could you pls look at my edit of the DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder?

Comment: Hi, yes sry, I got an nullpointer exception on that line and I changed only your code a bit. The problem lies however in @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 1;
    }
It can be normal links and mirror links need to be shown at the same time.
I used your code now but the mirror links are Always shown in the textview of download.text_item.
I`m gonna accept your answer once it works.

Comment: sorry but i just cant understand your requirement..please first clear what you want actually and then post appropriate question

Comment: Your code works but there is one thing missing.
Utils.downloadVis decides if there are mirrors or not (1: mirrors are present, 0: no mirrors). According to that condition the textview in mirror_text_item should be filled with the mirror links (fetched), for now I just set a text (Just a test) to see if it is shown.
It can be that both normal links and mirrors links are present so BOTH textviews (text, mir) should be filled and shown in the recyclerview.

Comment: As I see it, only @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) { return 1; } should be changed according that condition, then everything works.
As said, the text in tv (id: mir) is shown now but in the textview (id: text).
They (text) should be both filled/shown for both tvs (text, mir) acccording condition Utils.downloadvis == 1